# Can't do an AJAX call with Python and Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am still learning to do javascript and django and yesterday I tried to do a simple hello world ajax exercise.

Server logs show that python code is being called but somehow django/python does not return anything when I check the xmlhttp.responseText and responseXML in firebug.

**UPDATE:** I removed the checking of the http status returned so that code immediately goes to print the output from the server

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript example 1</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function doAjax() 
  {
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       alert("response text: "+xmlhttp.responseText+"\n"
             +"response XML: "+ xmlhttp.responseXML);
       if (xmlhttp.responseText!="") {
            $("thediv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       }      
   }   
   xmlhttp.open("GET","http://127.0.0.1/test/",true);
   xmlhttp.send(); 
  }
  function $(element){
    return document.getElementById(element);
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>

 <input type="button" value="click me" onClick=javascript:doAjax()>
 <br/><br/>

 <div id="thediv">
  some test
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

my views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
 response_string="hello"
 return HttpResponse(response_string,mimetype='text/plain')
```

my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from project1.views import test

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^test/$', test)
    # Example:
    # (r'^project1/', include('project1.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs' 
    # to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:
    # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the code in action

[image]

Comment: You import `json` from your views `from project1.views import json` and yet the url config points to `test`. Is this a typo?

Comment: Yep that's a typo. Sorry I changed it when I was typing in the question here. In my filesystem the original name of the method was json and it still is. Nevertheless same thing, still not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its good to use core JavaScript when learning but you should definitely use some framework such as `jQuery` or `Prototype` as you progress. Frameworks allow to keep your code concise, develop faster and also insulate you from the cross-browser compatibility issues.

Using jQuery your code would have been something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Javascript example 1</title>
 <script type=”text/javascript” src=”http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js”></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function doAjax() 
  {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8000/test/',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#thediv').html(data); //jQuery equivalent of  document.getElementById('thediv').innerHTML = data
      }
    });
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>

 <input type="button" value="click me" onClick="javascript:doAjax()"/>
 <br/><br/>

 <div id="thediv">
  some test
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Since jQuery provides with a default `$()` function, you do not need to define them in your code in case you use the framework.

Though this answer is slightly off-track, I hope it will be useful to you.

Comment: +1 for putting the jquery code. Yes I do plan to move on to using a framework but of course after I get my hands dirty with handmade javascript :D

Comment: This works....but not on Firefox 3.6.10 which I am using! Sucks :( I tried it on IE and it suddenly worked! @_@

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your code. When I clicked the "click me" button, a request was indeed made to the `test` view. I was able to confirm this. However, unlike what you said the view **is** returning the `HttpResponse`. To verify this yourself, access the `http://localhost:8000/test/` url using your web browser. See what happens.

At first blush your problem seems to be JavaScript related. I don't know what exactly is going wrong but I'll try to debug the JS code and see.

**Update**

I was able to confirm that the error is indeed with the JavaScript that you are using. I found two errors. First:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==0)
```

Shouldn't the `status` be `200`? So I changed it to:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
```

**Update 2**

Found that I missed the `$` function.

The problem is that there are *two* `if` conditions. When first evaluates to true, the contents of the div are indeed updated to "hello". However the second `if (xmlhttp.responseXML!="")` **also** evaluates to true (`null` is `!= ""`, hence) and wipes out the contents of the div.

Comment: Yes, when I go to the http://localhost:8000/test/ the browser indeed returns the "hello" string but when I do an ajax call using the button above, firebug shows that the responseText and responseXML are not showing anything.

Comment: My files are at home so I'll be able to check them tonight when I get back from the office. Will get back to you. I have a few comments though on your update, I checked my javascript in firebug and it does go through inside the if (xmlhttp.status=200) statement. Regarding the ($) shortcut key, I made a function in javascript that will return the element, see my code above --> function $(element) {...} Cheers :D

Comment: I tried setting the xmlhttp.status==200 in the if statement but nothing happens. So I am still using the xmlhttp.status==0 comparison. Like you I also placed an alert within inside the if statement and unlike you, as you can see above, nothing is being returned.

Comment: @Jeune: for what it is worth I tested the code in Chrome (6.0.472.62) and Firefox (3.6.10, Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu Canonical - 1.0) both on Ubuntu Jaunty.

Comment: Obviously it's a problem on MY end, as a developer. I tried this on two installations --- linux mint and as you can see above windows xp and both didn't work! :)) There's something I am doing wrong here :))

Comment: @Jeune: I also tested the answer given by @skimnetster It works :)

Comment: Are there settings I have to tweak? Should I put my index.html in a folder where the views.py is?

Comment: @Jeune: No need to tweak any settings. `Index.html` should preferably reside in your templates directory and not in the same directory as `views.py`.

Comment: I made a last change to the javascript code, would like to ask for your opinion before I try something new. I basically removed the if statement that checks the httpstatus and ready state.

Comment: @Jeune: looks good to me :) Try and see if it works for you. Although in the long run you'd be better off using a library like jQuery.

Comment: haha well actually my code change didn't work. Maybe I'll try some other way to do this. Thanks for all the help +1